# How to hande a very big list in HTML5?

Tags: html, performance, list, html-lists

a HTML5 web application has a page with a very big list. Now, it has 400 entries and may have much more later. I fear that it begins to become jerky in the future on mobile platforms when more data is filled in during time. It looks like a tableView. Very basic thing. There is nothing else but a hamburger menu.

Basically, it is an UL element that contains the LI elements. The body element grows with this UL element.

Each entry has one single keyword. It is sorted alphabetically (but half of content starts with the same character). It leads to a detail page.

There is a search bar that filters out matches, when in use. If the search bar is empty, all entries are shown (this is mandatory).

The problem is, that the content can't be really split up to categories. It is one single list.

The best would be a hidden performance trick because the GUI as is shouldn't be changed.

When I look to the UITableView of native apps, there is a trick: There are only a few rows. When a row leaves the visible portion during scrolling down, it is recycled and added at the bottom again (but with new content for that row). The user don't notice that and think that there are bunches of row elements. A UITableView is almost endless.

I've tried iScroll. But that also adds somewhat ugly look&feel during scrolling (did they reinvent the scrolling entirely?)

Can I archive that (or similar) in HTML5? I prefer a non-plugin solution, because many javascript plugins tends to bloat the entire application or to destroy its look&feel. I just need a performance kick for this big list. Or is there a trick to tell the browser that it should act like a UITableView here?

I also tried a css trick using transform:translateZ(0). That didn't work at all. Nothing is happening here.

The app itself is small and basically that "endless" list plus some small extra features.

The DOM is following:
html -> body -> div-container (for nice fading effect and sometimes moved a bit sideward to uncover the hamburger menu) -> ul and searchform ->li inside the ul

I don't see a way to optimze here.

PS: Is there a body height limitation? Or is my fear for no reason and the browser already do something to prevent a performance slowdown for such big lists?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Clusterize.js](https://clusterize.js.org/), you might be interested.
It was created exactly to solve performance problems like these.

Clusterize supports `<ol>, <ul>` lists and do not reinvent the scrolling, everything looks like native html scroll.